# Call ViewHelper from outside Fluid template

Tags: typo3, viewhelper

In my general page setup, I define the template as follows: `page.10.template.file = fileadmin/template.html`

Is there a way to call a MVC ViewHelper in this template? The snippet

```
{namespace xyz=PATH\TO\MY\ViewHelpers}
<xyz:myhelper argument="abc" />
```

does not work in the above template, it is surfaced as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not 100% clear for me, which cObject you use for your page template. If you would like to use Fluid ViewHelpers in your page template, then I would recommend to use FLUIDTEMPLATE for your page template.

**1. FLUIDTEMPLATE**

If you use [FLUIDTEMPLATE](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html) for your page template, then you can use any available ViewHelper (from FLUID or any other ExtBase/Fluid extension) directly in your template (see example below).

*TypoScript*

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
  template = FILE
  template.file = fileadmin/templates/template.html
  partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/Partials/
  layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/Layouts/
  variables {
    content < styles.content.get
    content.select.where = colPos=1
  }
}
```

*Content of file: fileadmin/templates/template.html*

```
{namespace xyz=NAMESPACE\EXTENSION\ViewHelpers}

<f:layout name="Main" />

<f:section name="Content">
  <xyz:myhelper argument="abc" />
  <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="">{content}</f:format.html>
</f:section>
```

*Content of file: fileadmin/templates/Layouts/Main.html*

```
<f:render section="Content" />
```

**2. TEMPLATE**

If you use [TEMPLATE](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Template/Index.html) (with markers and subparts), then you can't directly use Fluid ViewHelpers in that template. But you could define a marker which renders the FLUID ViewHelper like shown below.

*TypoScript*

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEMPLATE
page.10 {
  template = FILE
  template.file = fileadmin/templates/template.html
  marks {
    CONTENT < styles.content.get
    VIEWHELPER = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    VIEWHELPER {
      template = FILE
      template.file = fileadmin/templates/viewhelper.html
      partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/Partials/
      layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/Layouts/
    }
  }
  workOnSubpart = DOCUMENT
}
```

*Content of file: fileadmin/templates/template.html*

```
<!--###DOCUMENT### Start-->
###VIEWHELPER###
###CONTENT###
<!--###DOCUMENT### end-->
```

*Content of file: fileadmin/templates/viewhelper.html*

```
{namespace xyz=NAMESPACE\EXTENSION\ViewHelpers}

<f:layout name="Main" />

<f:section name="Content">
  <xyz:myhelper argument="abc" />
</f:section>
```

*Content of file: fileadmin/templates/Layouts/Main.html*

```
<f:render section="Content" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using both cObjects for page templates in various projects. Works really well this way!